# Numpy vectorization: comparing array against multiple values

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

Let's say in NumPy that we have

```
y = np.array([1,2,2,2,1,2])
classes=np.array([1,2])
```

We want to do `y==classes[0]` and `y==classes[1]` and put these together into a single array

```
[[ True, False, False, False,  True, False],
[False,  True,  True,  True, False,  True]]
```

Is there a vectorized way to construct this?

Comment: Use broadcasting to help you out here; put classes into a column vector and check equality. `y == classes[:, np.newaxis]`

Comment: Just `y == classes[:,None]` is enough.